# WPF - is there some kind of implicit conversion going on while databinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters

I just noticed that in some places in my project I forgot to use my Int/DoubleToStringValueConverter with my TwoWay bindings and still they have been working.

So is there some kind of implicit conversion there? I actually knew about the string->color, color->string conversion and I used that sometimes but not number->string, string->number. So could you recommend a documentation somewhere where I could read about when should I use a converter and when should I not?

Comment: I think there is another process (outside data binding) doing it for you. It is done by the so-called `TypeConverter`, such as for `Color` we have `ColorConverter`, for `int`, we have `Int32Converter`, ... This process is after binding completed. That means you can bind a `Color` property to some string representing color name, after that the color name will be converted to `Color` using `ColorConverter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Data Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview#data-conversion) section in the [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) article on MS Docs:

> [...] default conversions may be available because of type
> converters that are present in the type being bound to. This behavior
> will depend on which type converters are available in the target. If
> in doubt, create your own converter.
>
> The following are some typical scenarios where it makes sense to implement a data converter:
>
> • Your data should be displayed differently, depending on culture. For instance, you might want to implement a currency converter or a calendar date/time converter based on the conventions used in a particular culture.
>
> • The data being used is not necessarily intended to change the text value of a property, but is instead intended to change some other value, such as the source for an image, or the color or style of the display text. Converters can be used in this instance by converting the binding of a property that might not seem to be appropriate, such as binding a text field to the Background property of a table cell.
>
> • More than one control or multiple properties of controls are bound to the same data. In this case, the primary binding might just display the text, whereas other bindings handle specific display issues but still use the same binding as source information.
>
> • A target property has a collection of bindings, which is termed MultiBinding. For MultiBinding, you use a custom IMultiValueConverter to produce a final value from the values of the bindings. For example, color may be computed from red, blue, and green values, which can be values from the same or different binding source objects. See MultiBinding for examples and information.